# What does Sybase function REPLACE() do with char() attribute?

Tags: sql, replace, sybase

Can anyone explain what the attribute char(10) does in this replace function?  Doesn't seem to do anything. What's the purpose in putting `char(x)` as search-string in `replace` function

```
select replace('1234567890',char(10),'')
```

Comment: per [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx) `Tab-char(9),
Line feed-char(10),
Carriage return-char(13)`

Comment: char(10) is the ascii character with code 10 (a line feed)

Comment: Ah, thanks guys. Didnt think of it as ascii symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control character Values

Tab: char(9)

Line feed: char(10)

Carriage return: char(13)